# How to match every file but one in grunt concat?

Tags: regex, node.js, regex-negation, gruntjs

I'm using grunt to concatenate and minimize my js files, I use the following config for the `concat` part:

```
concat: {
  dist: {
    src: ['<banner:meta.banner>', 'js/*.js'],
    dest: 'js/script.js'
  }
}
```

It matches every file in my `js` folder but I need to ignore `modernizr.js`, is there a way to do this? I assume I'd need some pattern matching voodoo to do it but I'm not sure how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `'js/*.js'` is **not** a regex, it is a path selector (or whatever they are called). A regex would have been `js\/.*\.js` (`.*` instead of `*`, and escaping the dot, at least). I'd look into other ways of excluding files, it may have additional configurations.

Comment: You're right, it uses `minimatch` for file selection which converts expressions into JavaScript `RegExp` objects so it's not 100% regex

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Based on [documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) I would try:

```
js/!(modernizr).js
(js/)!(modernizr).js
{js/}!(modernizr).js
js/!({modernizr}).js
(js/)!({modernizr}).js
{js/}!({modernizr}).js
js/!{modernizr}.js
(js/)!{modernizr}.js
{js/}!{modernizr}.js
```

If none of them is going to work, then probably you are of out luck...

Comment: Thanks the first one worked fine, I was trying `js/!modernizr.js` before no wonder why it didn't work...

Comment: @javiervd - In `js/!modernizr.js` you used negation just for letter `m`, that's why it didn't work...