# How to continue if grunt-contrib-csslint throws error and how to exclude some files?

Tags: gruntjs

I tried specifying force: true for grunt-contrib-csslint to continue even if error occurs as follows, but it does not seem to work, kindly help.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

    // define source files and their destinations
    csslint:{
       options: {
           force: true,
           absoluteFilePathsForFormatters: true,
           formatters: [
               {id: 'compact', dest: 'quality/report/css/compact.xml'}
           ]
       },
       strict:{
           options:{
               force: true,
               import:2,
               "box-model":false,
           },
           src:['src/main/webapp/public/css/*.css'],
       },
       lax: {
            options: {
                import: false
            },
       src: ['src/main/webapp/public/css/ng-grid.css']
      }
   }
   });
   // load plugins
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-csslint');

       // register at least this one task
       grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'csslint' ]);
       };
       }};
```

The 'lax' property also does not seem to work and it still picks the files specified there? Kindly point out the problem with this also.

Thanks,
Paddy

Comment: Hi, Can somebody please let me know how to continue with csslint on errors and how to avoid writing to standard output when you have specified formatters? Please help, as I have not really been to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insert the following code in registerTask. 
You cannot set force option for csslint but you can set force option for grunt.

```
// set the grunt force option
grunt.option("force", true);

// register at least this one task
grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'csslint' ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To just run the `lax` option try:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'csslint:lax' ]);
```

If you want Grunt to continue on errors, run:

```
grunt --force
```

Comment: Hi @Ludder, how to specify the --force option in the Gruntfile.js config as shown above itself instead of command line? Also the 'csslint:lax' target was to ignore certain files, may be I need not have it all, but how do I instruct the 'csslint:strict' to ignore certain files?

Comment: Hi @Paddy, I'm afraid the `force` option works only command line. To ignore certain files try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11066185/373154).

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude certain files using  "!" in the csslint:check:src array as follows:

```
    csslint: {
        options: {
            csslintrc: '.csslintrc'
        },
        check: {
            src: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/css/**/*.css',
                '!<%= yeoman.app %>/_scss/**/*.scss'
            ]
        }
    },
```

In the case above (from the Grunfile.js file) we're telling grunt to process .css files, but to ignore .scss files.

Answer (score 0):

There is a npm package for running a specific task with force mode, so you don't have to use the force option globally.

It's called 'grunt-force-task' and can be found here: 
https://github.com/floriangosse/grunt-force-task

A solution for the csslint-question would look like this:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-csslint');
grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'force:csslint' ]);
```

Besides that running a specific task with force flag is in discussion in the grunt main repository atm. Maybe there will be some changes to grunt itself in the future. See:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/810