# Copy exception with grunt.js

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I'm trying to copy the content of a folder except one subfolder with grunt.js.

```
src/
src/folder1
src/folder2
src/folder3
```

How do I copy the content of `src` except `folder3` in `dist/`?

```
dist/
dist/folder1
dist/folder2
```

I'v tryed things with `!` but everythings failled :(.

```
copy: {
  main: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'src/',
    src: [
    '**',
    '!folder3'
    ],
    dest: 'dist/'
  }
}
```

Comment: perhaps '!/folder3**'. maybe  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064773/how-to-match-every-file-but-one-in-grunt-concat) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632029/grunt-minimatch-glob-folder-exclusion) helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I managed to do the job:

```
copy: {
   main: {
     expand: true,
     cwd: 'src/',
     src: [
     '**',
     '!**folder3/**'
     ],
     dest: 'dist/'
   }
 }
```